# How to iteratively create UNION ALL SQL statement using Python?

Tags: python, sql, list, loops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am connecting to `Snowflake` to query  row count data of view table from `Snowflake`. I am also querying metadata related to View table. My Query looks like below. I was wondering if I can iterate through UNION ALL statement using `python` ? When I try to run my below query I received an error that says "view_table_3" does not exist.

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts!

**Query to get row count for Snowflake view table (with metadata)**

```
view_tables=['view_table1','view_table2','view_table3','view_table4']

print(f""" SELECT * FROM (SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,CREATED,LAST_ALTERED FROM SCHEMA='INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS' WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='MY_SCHEMA' AND TABLE_NAME IN ({','.join("'" +x+ "'" for x in view_tables)})) t1

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 'view_table1' table_name2, count(*) as view_row_count from MY_DB.SCHEMA.view_table1
UNION ALL SELECT {','.join("'" +x+ "'" for x in view_tables[1:])},count(*) as view_row_count from MY_DB.SCHEMA.{','.join("" +x+ "" for x.replace("'"," ") in view_tables)})t2
on t1.TABLE_NAME =t2.table_name2 """)
```

Comment: What is `FROM SCHEMA='MY_SCHEMA'` supposed to mean? Are you missing `FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE`?

Comment: No..this is for VIEWS Table. To be precise it will be INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS

Comment: But you left out the `FROM` clause entirely, how is it supposed to know what table to query?

Comment: It should be `FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE SCHEMA = ...`

Comment: This code is not compilable in Python: `SyntaxError: f-string: cannot assign to function call` -likely here `for x.replace("'"," ")`. Always test what you post here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a union dynamically, put the entire `SELECT` query inside the generator, and then join them with `' UNION '`.

```
sql = f'''SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS AS v
LEFT JOIN (
    {' UNION '.join(f"SELECT '{table}' AS table_name2, COUNT(*) AS view_row_count FROM MY_SCHEMA.{table}" for table in view_tables)}
) AS t2 ON v.TABLE_NAME = t2.table_name2
WHERE v.TABLE_NAME IN ({','.join(f"'{table}'" for table in view_tables)})
'''
print(sql);
```

Comment: How would the ON statement work ? If possible please post code. Still receiving Syntaxerror" f-string: unmatched